# Нужна ли тут запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

"Я же сказал тебе(,) стоять и смотреть". Нужна тут запятая или нет?

Comment: Нет, не нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая здесь, конечно, неуместна, но при интонационной паузе нужен другой знак, например двоеточие, хотя возможно и тире

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. *Сказал* - сказуемое.  Сказал (что?) стоять. *Стоять* -  дополнение.